# Cordova 7.x reformats config.xml and package.json on run

Tags: cordova

When I use `cordova run android`, the *config.xml* and *package.json* files in the root of the project get reformatted. It happens only with Cordova 7.x, the 6.5.0 version leaves the files as they are. Also when I use `phonegap run android` which basically just calls `cordova run android`, the files are left unchanged.

The changes:

In ***config.xml***, the tags get reordered, spaces are added to the end of self-closing tag (`<sometag />` instead of `<sometag/>`) and the quotation marks in the `<?xml>` tag on the first line of the file are changed from double quotes (*"*) to single quotes (*'*).

In ***package.json***, the indentation is changed from 2 spaces to 4 spaces and all the Cordova plugins (previously specified only in *config.xml*) are added under the `dependencies` key. Also, a new top-level `cordova` key is added with the defined Cordova platforms (also from *config.xml*) and all the Cordova plugins (once again).

Does anyone have any idea why? And mainly how to suppress this behaviour besides sticking to Cordova 6.5.0? I need a configurable project-wise solution so that it doesn't happen to the other developers too.

Comment: Just a tip: Stick with 6.5.0 for now since apache changed a lot of things running under the hood. Some of them are still broken or require work arounds. If you have further questions, please check out the release notes: https://cordova.apache.org/blog/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll follow the advice. Looks like I'll rather have to find a way to prevent the other devs from updating.

Comment: Hey, thanks for creating this question zbr. @P.Stresow, how stable is Cordova 7 now? is it still quite broken? Should I still stick with 6.5.0? I see that there have been some updates since then in regards to this question / issue

Comment: Interesting, I'm planing to migrate to Cordova 7.1.0. 
Is the migration from 6.5.0 safe now? tkx

Answer (score 3):

This also bothered me for **package.json**: Cordova 7.0.0 uses JSON.stringify to save the updated package.json file after a modification is done (as well as npm when using the `--save` flag) .

They just happened to choose a different indentation of 4 spaces.

A PR has a already been approved by the team to make this change:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/558

**Edit:** This commit was marged to master. It should be present in the newer versions of cordova.